# Wordpress different products category pages with different widgets

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget, filtering

I am making this wordpress based website ( https://naujas.pacopac.lt/ ), it is for company with multiply product categories and in every category page I want to have filter system by different attributes.

I tried to create page for every category, but the problem is that I can add products of certain category, but I can not filter them then. Also I can only add filtering through widget.

So the way i see to make it is by directing people to product category page, like `https://naujas.pacopac.lt/product-category/“name of category”/`. For example `https://naujas.pacopac.lt/product-category/pakuotes/` , add widget with filtering and then it works. BUT every category has to be filtered with different attributes, and I am only able to add one same widget to all categories pages and I can not find a way in WordPress to edit every each of these category pages, also I can only make one side widget.

So in short the problem is, how can I make different Side widgets and edit every each of product category pages with different widgets? I am using uncode theme with woocommerce and visual composer, would like to avoid coding, but also have basic knowledge in it so something not too complicated could be done.  Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with Widget Logic plugin, able to show widgets on certain pages and hide others